# SQL Server 2005 or LINQ query: joining two tables and calculate field

Tags: sql, linq, sql-server-2005

I have two tables with the same structure: `Table1` (Original) and `Table2` (Updated)

I must to keep all the data from `Table1` without changes.

`Table2` could have 1 or all the rows from `Table1` with the same information EXCEPT one column `QUANTITY` that could vary from the original.

I would like a query where we join the two tables, and as result show all the rows from `Table1` but when exist a match in `Table2`, show the row from `Table2` instead, discarding the row from `Table1` and showing the sum or substract of the column `QUANTITY`.

Example:

**Table1**

```
Product    Quantity

Shirt      3
Pants      5
Shoes      9
```

**Table 2**

```
Product    Quantity

Pants      2
```

Result:

```
Product    Quantity
---------------
Shirt      3
Pants      3
Shoes      9
```

Is that possible from one single query, or should I use extra code (I'm using C# and LINQ)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var query = from table1 in data.Table1s
                join table2 in data.Table2s
                on table1.ID equals table2.ID
    into x            
    select new {
        table1.Shirt,
        Pants = x.Sum(c=>c.Pants) + table1.Pants,
        table1.Shoes
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Well it all depends on your table layout, I would suggest having an Active flag in your table so that you do not remove the record from table1, but rather just set it as inactive. Then you could use a [**Case Statement**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) to do exactly what you want.

So add a column to table 1 (IsActive) with datatype [bit](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177603.aspx) the use the following query:

```
DECLARE @tResult TABLE
(ProductName varchar(max),
 ProductQTY int,
 ToSetInactive int)



       INSERT INTO @tResult
       Select
        ProductName,
        CASE WHEN tbl1.ProductName =  tbl2.ProductName THEN DO YOUR LOGIC HERE ELSE DO SOME OTHER LOGIC HERE END AS QTY,
       ProductName,
        CASE WHEN tbl1.ProductName = tbl2.ProductName THEN tbl1.Id ELSE 0 END AS ToSetAsInactive
       From Table1 tbl1     
      INNER JOIN Table2 tbl2 on tbl2.ProductName = tbl2.ProductName

     UPDATE TABLE1 set IsActive WHERE ID in (select ToSetInactive from @tResult) 

     Select * From @Result
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

```
select table1.product, isnull(table1.quantity - table2.quantity, table1.quantity) as Quantity 
from table1
left join table2
on table1.product = table2.product
```